# PHP 7 - Alternative Syntax else if that has HTML inside?

Tags: php

my apologies if there's an answer to this on SO somewhere. I searched around with no avail.

I'm wondering if there's alternative syntax for else if with HTML inside exists. I know there's such alternative syntax for if and else, but couldn't find anything in the PHP documentation for else if.

Right now I have this code:

```
<?php if($err) : ?>
    <div class="alert-failure"><?php echo "Error: " . $err; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($success): ?>
    <div class="alert-success"><?php echo "Success: " . $success; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But this seems illogical since my app won't be having an error if it's successful. Is there a way to use else if here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: alert != error, an alert can be successful

Comment: also alternative, `<?php echo "` should be `<?= "`, and without all the `; ?>`

Comment: you can use only one variable, i.e. if success then flag = 1, else if error then flag = 2, and if nothing then flag = 0... then you can use PHP shorthand/ternary if else condition... https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: I didn't know I can do that Lawrence! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be -

```
<?php ($err) ? '<div class="alert-failure">Error: ' . $err . '</div>' : 
(($success) ? '<div class="alert-success">Success: ' . $success . '</div>' : '') ?>
```

It is somewhat similar like -

```
if($err) { //... }
elseif($success) { //... }
```

Comment: ugly imo, whats with the additional `()` wraps, add a few more, go on ;p...

Comment: The additionals `()` are for understanding the groupings. also helps when it minds the operator precision. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this! II feel silly for not realizing I could put the html as a string inside Ternary. My only gripe with this sort of solution is I feel that readability suffers. Although I suppose I can add a comment explaining this so it doesn't have to be deciphered..

Comment: I had to surround the output in a print() statement for this to output HTML. I discarded the extra parenthesis as well as they weren't necessary in this case. You may want to modify your future for the benefit of anybody who stumbles upon this in the future!

Answer (score 4):

You could use  `Ternary` it is simple, easy to read, and would look like this:

```
$value = ($condition) ? 'Truthy Value' : 'Falsey Value';
```

**What Are The Advantages of Ternary Logic?**

There are some valuable advantages to using this type of logic:

- Makes coding simple if/else logic quicker
- You can do your if/else logic inline with output instead of breaking
  your output building for if/else statements
- Makes code shorter
- Makes maintaining code quicker, easier

Comment: Would you mind linking me to where you found the excerpt at the bottom of your answer? Or did you just write it out?

Comment: no i didn't write that one.. copied from here : https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: Thank you! @Bilal